# Passing data to a thread using Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  new Thread (() => Console.Write (i)).Start();
```

As expected the output of the above code is non-deterministic, because i variable refers to the same memory location throughout the loop’s lifetime. Therefore, each thread calls Console.Write on a variable whose value may change as it is running

However,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  int temp = i;
  new Thread (() => Console.Write (temp)).Start();
}
```

Is also giving non-deterministic output! I thought variable temp was local to each loop iteration. Therefore, each thread captured a different memory location and there should have been np  problem.

Comment: What is the non-deterministic nature of the output?

Comment: The second version should work - Eric Lippert blogged about closures over loop variables here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: It shouldn't be "deterministic" as "the order of threads scheduled is always the same". Maybe that's what the question means?

Comment: do u mean that your output should be printed as 123...9?

Comment: And the question is similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168375/c-using-the-iterator-variable-of-foreach-loop-in-a-lambda-expression-why-fai/3168381#3168381

Comment: Regarding the temp variable; as int is a primitive, I'd expect that both calls would act the same as i would be passed by value. It's just that the thread execution and completion order can't be guaranteed the way you've structured your code.

Comment: @JeffWatkins the int is a primitive, but because it is captured in a closure, it is actually stored in a heap object.  The first sample creates one closure object on the heap, and all 10 threads use that one object.  The second example creates 10 different closure objects on the heap, one for each thread.  Follow Paolo's link to Eric Lippert's blog, or read Honza Brestan's answer for a brief discussion.

Comment: variables referenced by lambda expressions are by reference, not by value Jeff

Comment: @phoog, very interesting, thanks. That has probably saved me a head scratcher in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program should have 10 lambdas, each writing one of the digits from 0 to 9 to the console.  However, there's no guarantee that the threads will execute in order.

Comment: There is no line break in OP's code, so the all digits will be on the only line.

Comment: @AgentFire ah, I see.  I saw "WriteLine" where there is only "Write".  I've edited the answer a bit.

Comment: Console.Write() *is* threadsafe, in that whole strings written to it will *never* have their characters interleaved.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you're right.  The output I described was based on an experience I had recently at work, but that must have resulted from multiple calls to the console on different threads.  I'll check it when I get to the office.

Answer (score 2):

> Is also giving non-deterministic output!

No, its not. I have checked ten times your first code (had repeating numbers) and the second (had not).

So it all works fine. Just as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The *second* code snippet should be deterministic in the sense that each thread eventually writes its `temp`, and all their temps will differ.

However, it does not guarantee that threads will be scheduled for execution in the order of their creation. You'll see all possible temps, but not necessarily in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proof that OP is right and both pieces of his code are incorrect.

And there is also a solution with proof also.

However need to note that **'non-deterministic' means that the threads receive wrong parameter**. *The order will be **never** guaranteed.*

The code below examines second piece of OP code and demonstrates that it is working as expected..

I am storing the pair (thread identity, parameter) and then print it to compare with the thread output to prove the pairs aren't changed. I also added few hundreds millisecond random sleep so the for index should obviously change at those times.

```
        Dictionary<int, int> hash = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int temp = i;
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(9) * 100);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
                    Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode(), temp);
            });

            hash.Add(th.GetHashCode(), temp);

            th.Start();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var kvp in hash)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```