# Making a void dynamic

Tags: c#, winforms, events, dynamic, void

I create some picture box dynamic, but i dont know how to make a individual action on click.

```
PictureBox[] app=new PictureBox[file.Length];
int i = 0, prev=20;
foreach(string element in file)
{
    app[i] = new PictureBox();
    app[i].BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(element.Remove(element.Length - 3) + "png");
    app[i].Location = new Point(prev, 85);
    app[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
    app[i].Name = "test" + i;
    app[i].Click += new EventHandler(run(element, dir));

    this.Controls.Add(app[i]);

    i++; 
    prev += 20;
}

private void run(string element, string dir)
{
      MessageBox.Show(element);
}
```

So how can I do that. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using delegates/functions within a foreach loop,  and if you do, use a copy of the object, not the variable in the loop statement.

```
var elementCopy = element;
...
app[i].Click += (sender,evt) => run(elementCopy,dir);
```

If you use the element directly, there is a chance it will always use the last element in the enumerable for the delegate

Edit: Refer to this: [Using the iterator variable of foreach loop in a lambda expression - why fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168375/using-the-iterator-variable-of-foreach-loop-in-a-lambda-expression-why-fails)

It explains why you should do what I said more in-depth.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want?

```
app[i].Click += (sender, args) => { MessageBox.Show(element);};
```

Comment: You don't need the braces around the body of your lambda.  `(sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(element)` would suffice and is cleaner.

Comment: Its all about the preferences. i prefer the curlies

Comment: This will still cause issue do the foreach iterator, and always display the last element

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app[i].Click += (s, e) => { run(element,dir); };
```