# C# - For loop and the lambda expressions

Tags: c#, for-loop, lambda

my question is why i'm getting wrong results using a iterator variable in a lambda expression.

Well i've followed SWeko's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168375/using-the-iterator-variable-of-foreach-loop-in-a-lambda-expression-why-fails). but it did not worked for me
Here is my pseudo-code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(3);
// where list.Count=3
for (int i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
    int yy=i;
    AFunctionWithLambda(() => Console.WriteLine (list[yy]));
}
```

But the console only writes

```
list[3]
```

three times, as if the only value which "yy" could be is the last value of "i"
It seemed to work because before declaring the "yy" variable, the Console returned "i=1" but it doesn't really, i don't know what i am mising.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: What is `AFunctionWithLambda` ? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and you didn't show how the list was populated.  the value of list[yy] could be 3 in all cases of yy.

Comment: The specifics **really, really** matter for this type of question. Can you perhaps show a minimal repro example? In particular, the *exact* code of `i`/`yy`, and we need to know whether the lambda is invoked *now*, versus held as a delegate and executed later vs executed asynchronously.

Comment: It is extremely unclear as to why you are declaring `yy` in the first place. We need to know the contents of `list` and see the `AFunctionWithLambda` method.

Comment: also: if `list.Count=3`, then `list[3]` doesn't make sense in the first place

Comment: @IAbstract actually, that bit *is* obvious; this is the notorious captured variable / loop problem - it has now been fixed for `foreach`, but still applies to `for` loops

Comment: @MarcGravell: I was unaware of the captured variable issue. I guess I instinctively avoided this sort of capture in a loop.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior. LinqPadDemo: `void Main()
{
 List<string> list = new List<string>(){ "1","2","3" };
 // where list.Count=3
 for (int i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
  int yy=i;
  AFunctionWithLambda(() => Console.WriteLine (list[yy]));
 }
}

public void AFunctionWithLambda(Action action)
{
 action();
}`

Comment: @IAbstract it's just an example, 'list' is only to show why i'm using the for-loop, `yy` is a variable declared to "capture" the value of the loop-variable, and `AFunctionWithLambda` is only a generic function, (it is `UnityEngine - Button.onClick.AddListener(UnityAction)` where i can convert `void` to `UnityAction` using lambda) i mean, the lambda-code only returns one value of `i` and not the three ones in the for-loop

Comment: @Jotarata you could just use `foreach`... assuming you're using a recent compiler, it doesn't suffer from the capture issue. If it still fails: your bug is probably elsewhere

Comment: @MarcGravell so if i use `foreach` instead of `for`, it should work?

Comment: @Jotarata "it should work"... well, the code you show should work ;p I wonder if the real problem here is that the list is changing contents, and your delegate is accessing **by index**. Switching to `foreach` would mean that you are working with the values *as read during the loop*, which is probably what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from your example, because it seems to be perfectly formed and correctly capturing. Here is my expanded version, and it works fine:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(3)
        { "a", "b", "c"};
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int yy = i;
            AFunctionWithLambda(() => Console.WriteLine(list[yy]));
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("all done, probably");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void AFunctionWithLambda(Action action)
    {  // runs it asynchronously, for giggles
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {
            Thread.Sleep(500); // delay, to let the loop finish
            action();
        });
    }
```

If you change it to:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            AFunctionWithLambda(() => Console.WriteLine(list[i]));
        }
```

then it fails in the way described separately.

We will need a better example ;p

Comment: yes i just wrote a very short code to explain it, but if we take your code, we should get at Console output: `a,b,c`, but instead i get only the value of `c`, that's what i tried to mean with `list[3]`

Comment: @Jotarata `c` would be `list[2]` - `list[3]` will throw an exception; but without seeing the content of your list **at the time the delegates are invoked**, it is meaningless to speculate. It could correctly be the case that it is all `c` *at that time*. Hence the distinction between `for` and `foreach`; the `foreach` approach captures the *values*; the `for` approach captures the *indices*

Comment: it is possible to get indices with `foreach` loop?  (ps:yes it should be list[2] instead xd)

Comment: @Jotarata why would you want to? and: no

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you're trying to do. To accomplish it you need the following:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
    String s=list[i] ;
    AFunctionWithLambda(() => Console.WriteLine(s));
}
```

I assume AFunctionWithLambda is adding the action to a list of actions? Then you are executing these actions after this for loop? With your code, all of the actions had a reference to i, which at the end of the for loop was set to 3. When each of your actions run i is still set to 3. With the method above we are creating 3 separate strings and action has its own reference to the correct string.

Make sure you populate your list of strings otherwise you're not going to get any output.

Comment: By the time you've done that, it would have been easier to just `foreach(var s in list) { AFunctionWithLambda(() => Console.WriteLine(s)); }`. I don't disagree, note - I'm just clarifying.

Comment: That depends on the .NET version you are running. In 5,yes,you could do this and it would work as expected. In 4 you would need to create another string in the for each loop and reference it in the action.  foreach(var s in list) { var copy = s; AFunctionWithLambda(()  => Console.WriteLine(copy)) ;}

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on the .NET version; it depends on the *compiler* version. But yes, the scope of the variable changed.

Comment: Apologies, yes, it would work for the c# 5 compiler. This has nothing to do with scope; this is all about creating a new string constant and referencing the correct one in the action.

Comment: actually, it has everything to do with scope. Sorry, but I've had a lengthy discussion about this topic (over chicken, IIRC) with Eric, Mads and Anders. It comes down to where the l-value is declared. In the 2.0 spec, the l-value was stated in the specification as being *outside* the loop - i.e. how `foreach` is expanded to actual code (`while`). In the later spec (and, oddly, in the 1.2 spec appendix for "definite assignment", IIRC) it is stated as being *inside* the loop. The captured variable logic is **very** sensitive to scope; inside=per iteration; outside=global to the loop.

Comment: oh, and that isn't a constant

Comment: to be explicit: the difference is: `foreach(SomeType x in foo) {...}` expanding to `{ SomeType x; while(iter.MoveNext()) {x = iter.Current; ...}` vs `{while(iter.MoveNext) { SomeType x = iter.Current; ...}`. There's some `using(var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator()) {...}` in there too, but it doesn't change between the two, so I have omitted it - plus it has lots of edge cases.

Comment: A string is immutable and a constant. Once you declare a string you cannot change that string. If you perform any action on a string such as appending, then you are essentially creating a brand new string. The other string will wait to be garbage collected unless you have another variable pointing to it. Scope is definitely not the reason why my code works, otherwise the OPs code would have worked. He scoped his yy int, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Yes a string is immutable. That is not what "a constant" means, though, and it is irrelevant here as "captured variables" capture (oddly enough) variables, not values - it is a full lexical closure. The thing at the end of the reference is completely irrelevant to this story. Sorry, but you have fundamentally misunderstood what is happening in this scenario.

Comment: IMO the reason the OP's code isn't working is that they are registering a callback (event handler, essentially) that has captured an index, and have subsequently *mutated the list* before that callback gets invoked. `foreach` would neatly circumnavigate that problem, but that doesn't make any of the rest accurate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the lesson. I'll maybe need to pump this in to vs tomorrow morning. Not that I don't take your word for it, I've clearly confused some things. And after reading through what you've said, it makes complete sense. It's not actually something I've needed to use in the real world, so I've never actually tinkered, just seen it mentioned in a few places. And yes, a string variable is not a constant (the string value is though.. Right? Do I get away with that?) Nearly 2am; tired, confused, and now I've got a sore head!

Comment: Heh, I'm in the UK, so 2am here too :) the concept of "constant" is only really defined in the compiler and in the IL, not at runtime. Strings are (at least, to the outside world) *immutable*, but that's not quite the same - but close. It is a very complex and nuanced area - I only had the need to understand it because I started doing a lot of IL work (and because I've read pretty much every version of the C# spec *for curiosity*, which makes interesting-ish reading)

Comment: Ah cool, I'm over in N.Ireland. I think I've got a few years left in me before I start looking at IL in any depth. From what I've seen it all seemed reasonable until dynamic became a thing. Was good chatting, and thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding of what was happening in this instance. (I think it might have stemmed from me watching a Skeet video on pluralsight - I guess I wasn't paying close enough attention!)

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here for anyone coming along after us & also for me to read through tomorrow: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: sorry but using `foreach` and `for (..){var t=foo[i]`didn't worked for me, i still get the same result with both, i'm getting the last value of the list

Comment: You need to show us all of your code. The issue is when you write to the console yet you haven't shown us how you are executing the actions, or even what AFunctionWithLambda does.

Answer (score 0):

I thing i've got a solution:

I can't use the loop-variable inside a lambda expression, but i can create a new method to do that.

and it will be something like

```
{
for (int i=0;i<list.count;i++){
    ToAction(i);
    }
}
void ToAction(int value){
    AFunctionWithLambda(()=>Console.WriteLine(list[value]);
}
```

and it works fine

Thanks to everyone who ask this (stupid) question :D