# Thread Summing computation error

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

my task is, to sum up numbers in some range, to achieve that I have to use threads to separate computation.
I divided number to parts and used a thread for each part.

```
 public class ParallelCalc
{
    public  long resultLong;
    private Thread[] threads;
    private List<long> list = new List<long>();

    public long MaxNumber { get; set; }
    public int ThreadsNumber { get; set; }

    public event CalcFinishedEventHandler finished;

    public ParallelCalc(long MaxNumber, int ThreadsNumber)
    {
        this.MaxNumber = MaxNumber;
        this.ThreadsNumber = ThreadsNumber;
        this.threads = new Thread[ThreadsNumber];
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
        {

            threads[i] = new Thread(() =>  Sum(((MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber) * i) + 1, 
                MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber * (i + 1)));

            if (i == ThreadsNumber - 1)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(() => Sum(((MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber) * i) + 1,
                                    MaxNumber));
            }

            sw.Start();
            threads[i].Start();
        }

        while (threads.All(t => t.IsAlive));
        sw.Stop();

        finished?.Invoke(this,
           new CalcFinishedEventArgs()
           {
               Result = list.Sum(),
               Time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
           });
    }


    private void Sum(long startNumber, long endnumber)
    {
        long result = 0;

        for (long i = startNumber; i <= endnumber; i++)
        {
            result += i;
        }

        list.Add(result);

    }

}
```

The result has to be the sum of numbers, however, it is incorrect due to thread asynchronous assignment in list. Please indicate the error.

Comment: You're using many shared variables, most of which have types assumed to be unsafe for multi-threaded access. Why do you expect us to diagnose your issues when you've put so little effort into correcting it yourself?

Comment: Only thing I ask is what to use in this case to obtain correct results fom multiple threads.

Comment: You should use a [Parallel.For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) instead.

Comment: It's not just the List, you're also capturing the `i` and then use it quite a bit.

Comment: Calculate how many segments you will have and use that to create  `new List<> (capacity)`, or just create an array. Then you can replace `list.Add(result)` with `list[index] = result` which _is_ thread-safe. Your answer still won't be right, see my comment about capturing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea let me try and respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one thing wrong here, brace yourself...

- `Start` creates a `Stopwatch sw`, but you call `sw.Start` on every iteration of the loop. Start it only once.
- if `i == ThreadsNumber - 1` evaluates to `true`, you let `Thread` to garbage. I fail to grasp why...

  ```
  (MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber) * (i + 1) WHEN i == ThreadsNumber - 1
  =
  (MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber) * (ThreadsNumber - 1 + 1)
  =
  (MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber) * (ThreadsNumber)
  =
  MaxNumber
  ```

  Do you have rounding problems? Rewrite like this:

  ```
  ((i + 1) * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber
  ```

  By dividing last, you avoid the rounding problem.
- You are spin waiting on the threads `while (threads.All(t => t.IsAlive));`. You could as well use `Thread.Join` or better yet, let the threads notify you when they are done.
- The ranges in the lambdas have a closure on `i`. You need to be careful with [C# - For loop and the lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683903/c-sharp-for-loop-and-the-lambda-expressions).
- `List<T>` is not thread safe. I would suggest to use a simple array (you know the number of threads afterall) and tell each thread to store only on the position that corresponds to them.
- You have not considered what would happen if a second call to `Start` happens before the first one finishes.

---

So, we will have an array for the output:

```
var output = new long[ThreadsNumber];
```

And one for the Threads:

```
var threads = new Thread[ThreadsNumber];
```

*Hmm, almost like we should create a class.*

We will have the stopwatch:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
```

Let us start it once:

```
sw.Start();
```

Now a `for` to create the Threads:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Have a copy of `i` to prevent problems:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    // ...
}
```

Compute the range for the current thread:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var start = 1 + (i * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
    var end = ((i + 1) * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
    // ...
}
```

We need to write `Sum` in such way that we can store the output in the array:

```
private void Sum(long startNumber, long endNumber, int index)
{
    long result = 0;
    for (long i = startNumber; i <= endnumber; i++)
    {
        result += i;
    }
    output[index] = result;
}
```

*Hmm... wait, there is a better way...*

```
private static void Sum(long startNumber, long endNumber, out long output)
{
    long result = 0;
    for (long i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++)
    {
        result += i;
    }
    output = result;
}
```

*Hmm... no, we can do better...*

```
private static long Sum(long startNumber, long endNumber)
{
    long result = 0;
    for (long i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++)
    {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Create the `Thread`

```
for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var start = 1 + (i * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
    var end = ((i + 1) * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
    threads[i] = new Thread(() => output[index] = Sum(start, end));
    // ...
}
```

And start the `Thread`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var start = 1 + (i * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
    var end = ((i + 1) * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
    threads[i] = new Thread(() => {output[index] = Sum(start, end);});
    threads[i].Start();
}
```

Are we really going to wait on these?

*Think, think...*

We keep track of how many threads are pending... and when they are all done, we call the event (and stop the Stopwatch).

```
var pendingThreads = ThreadsNumber;

// ...

for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
{
    // ...
    threads[i] = new Thread
    (
        () =>
        {
            output[index] = Sum(start, end);
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pendingThreads) == 0)
            {
                sw.Stop();
                finished?.Invoke
                (
                    this,
                    new CalcFinishedEventArgs()
                    {
                        Result = output.Sum(),
                        Time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );
    // ...
}
```

---

Let us bring it all togheter:

```
void Main()
{
    var pc = new ParallelCalc(20, 5);
    pc.Finished += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args);
    };
    pc.Start();
}

public class CalcFinishedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public long Result {get; set;}
    public long Time {get; set;}
}

public class ParallelCalc
{
    public long MaxNumber { get; set; }
    public int ThreadsNumber { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<CalcFinishedEventArgs> Finished;

    public ParallelCalc(long MaxNumber, int ThreadsNumber)
    {
        this.MaxNumber = MaxNumber;
        this.ThreadsNumber = ThreadsNumber;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var output = new long[ThreadsNumber];
        var threads = new Thread[ThreadsNumber];
        var pendingThreads = ThreadsNumber;
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
        {
            var index = i;
            var start = 1 + (i * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
            var end = ((i + 1) * MaxNumber) / ThreadsNumber;
            threads[i] = new Thread
            (
                () =>
                {
                    output[index] = Sum(start, end);
                    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pendingThreads) == 0)
                    {
                        sw.Stop();
                        Finished?.Invoke
                        (
                            this,
                            new CalcFinishedEventArgs()
                            {
                                Result = output.Sum(),
                                Time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
            threads[i].Start();
        }
    }

    private static long Sum(long startNumber, long endNumber)
    {
        long result = 0;
        for (long i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++)
        {
            result += i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Result
210 

Time
0
```

That is too fast... let me input:

```
var pc = new ParallelCalc(2000000000, 5);
pc.Finished += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(args);
};
pc.Start();
```

Output:

```
Result
2000000001000000000 

Time
773
```

[And that is correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(summation+from+k+%3D+0+to+k+%3D+2000000000+of+k)+%3D+2000000001000000000).

And yes, this code takes care of the case of calling `Start` multiple times. Notice that it create a new array for the output and a new array of threads each time. That way, it does not trip over itself.

*I let error handling to you. Hints: `MaxNumber / ThreadsNumber` -> division by 0, and `(i + 1) * MaxNumber` -> overflow, not to mention `output.Sum()` -> overflow.*