# Result is not getting while multicasting

Tags: c#, delegates

I am using a delegate type to call multiple functions from a single point. But when I do like that , I am getting the result somewhat wrong.

```
public delegate int MyDel(int a,int b);

public static int Add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
public static int Sub(int a, int b) { return a-b; }


public static void Meth_del()
{
   int x,y;
   MyDel _delegate;
   _delegate = Add;
   _delegate += Sub;
   Console.WriteLine( _delegate(5,4));
}
```

Here I should get result 9 and then 1 but only 1 is printed. How ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the iterator variable of foreach loop in a lambda expression - why fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168375/using-the-iterator-variable-of-foreach-loop-in-a-lambda-expression-why-fails)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes its quite obvious that the last method in the delegate will returns the result.

```
public static void Meth_del()
{
   int x,y;
   MyDel _delegate;
   _delegate = Add;
   Console.WriteLine( _delegate(5,4));
   _delegate += Sub;
   Console.WriteLine( _delegate(5,4));
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful without a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Closure. This happens because on the call it will execute both of the subscribed methods and you will be shown with end result.

To avoid such behavior you can unsubscribe (`_delegate = null`), override subscribers (`=`) or subscribe (`+=`) after first call is made.

```
public static void Meth_del()
{
   int x,y;
   MyDel _delegate;
   _delegate = Add;
   // Prints out 9.  
   Console.WriteLine( _delegate(5,4));
   // Override subscribtion.
   _delegate = Sub;
  // Prints out 1.
  Console.WriteLine( _delegate(5,4));
}
```

Also you can use `+=` to add subscribers to the delegate (as you have written in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Even if both methods are called only the the last method in the delegate will return the result.

Furthermore, you have only one call of `Console.WriteLine()`, a function cannot receive multiple return values.

To achieve what you want you might have to queue your results like this.

```
public static Queue<int> Results = new Queue<int>(); 

public static void Add(int a, int b) { Results.Enqueue(a + b); }
public static void Sub(int a, int b) { Results.Enqueue(a - b); }

public delegate void MyDel(int a, int b);

public static void Meth_del()
{
    int x, y;
    MyDel _delegate;
    _delegate = Add;
    _delegate += Sub;
    _delegate(5, 4);
    while (Results.Any()) 
        Console.WriteLine(Results.Dequeue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does execute both methods but it only displays the return value of the last added method. If you change your methods like this:

```
public static int Add(int a, int b) { 
    Console.WriteLine(a+b);
    return a+b; 
}
public static int Sub(int a, int b) { 
    Console.WriteLine(a-b);
    return a-b;
}
```

you will see that 9 as well as 1 are written in the console.